# Как вывести телефон в красивом формате?

Tags: php

Есть небольшая функция которая обрабатывает номер телефона перед выводом, проблема в том-что функция некорректно отображает телефон, например номер записан 9061755555,то она отображает в формате (906)175-55-55.Есть еще момент что в базе некоторые телефоны могут быть в украинские, российские... Как дописать функцию чтобы она подставляла +3 если ее нет или +7 в общем форматировала телефон красиво...

```
function echoNumber($aphone) // номер в формате (xxx) xxx-xx-xx
{
   $sArea = substr($aphone, 0, 3);
   $sNumber1 = substr($aphone, 3, 3);
   $sNumber2 = substr($aphone, 6, 2);
   $sNumber3 = substr($aphone, 8, 2);
   $aphone = "(" . $sArea . ") " . $sNumber1 . "-" . $sNumber2 . "-" . $sNumber3;
   return ($aphone);
}
```

Comment: *"в общем форматировала телефон красиво"* - это программирование, здесь нет "красиво", здесь фигурируют только формальные  определения алгоритмов с детерминированным выводом.

Comment: Что значит "некорректно отображает телефон" в первом предложении, если она и должна выводить "номер в формате (xxx) xxx-xx-xx", если она именно так его и выводит?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[libphonenumber for PHP](https://github.com/giggsey/libphonenumber-for-php)

```
$swissNumberStr = "9061755555";
$phoneUtil = \libphonenumber\PhoneNumberUtil::getInstance();
try {
    $swissNumberProto = $phoneUtil->parse($swissNumberStr, "RU");
    echo $phoneUtil->format($swissNumberProto, \libphonenumber\PhoneNumberFormat::NATIONAL);
} catch (\libphonenumber\NumberParseException $e) {
    var_dump($e);
}
```

[Демо](https://giggsey.com/libphonenumber/?phonenumber=9061755555&country=RU&language=&region=)

Comment: Пожалуйста, постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Уверен, автор вопроса был бы благодарен за ваш экспертный комментарий к приведенному выше коду.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky честно говоря не знаю что тут можно добавить кроме как -"Вы можете попробовать библиотеку ..., работает примерно вот так:" Ну все остальное узнать можно из документации к библиотеке. Буду благодарен если укажите тезисами что можно тут добавить.

Answer (score 1):

```
function echoNumber($aphone) // номер в формате (xxx) xxx-xx-xx
{
    $lengthOfString = strlen($aphone);

    $codeOfCountry = "";
    if($lengthOfString  > 10 && stristr($phone, '+') === false) {
        if (substr($phone, 0, 1) == 8) {
            $codeOfCountry = "+7";
        } else {
            $codeOfCountry = "+" . substr($phone, 0, $lengthOfString-10);
        }
    } else {
        $codeOfCountry = "+7";
    }

    $sArea = substr($aphone, 0, 3);
    $sNumber1 = substr($aphone, 3, 3);
    $sNumber2 = substr($aphone, 6, 2);
    $sNumber3 = substr($aphone, 8, 2);
    $aphone = $codeOfCountry . "(" . $sArea . ") " . $sNumber1 . "-" . $sNumber2 . "-" . $sNumber3;
    return $aphone;
}
```

Если именно переписать, то так (и если в базе данных хранятся номера одного формата). А вообще, для этих целей лучше использовать JS, которая бы уже приводила номер телефона в нужный вид, добавляя проверки - благо там есть подходящие библиотеки.

Comment: ну зачем писать функцию в функции и забывать про скобки `{}`

Comment: И правда, исправил.

Comment: так компакней и виднее но всё равно у вас не учтено что телефон храниться без кода страны.

Comment: что-то вышло не то... было https://gyazo.com/c5f9cb9d92f00e0083c0dcaf35c2dd53 стало https://gyazo.com/64fdb2a1be69144ef5897b29fb97ee38

Comment: Это вам так substr делит, он рассчитан только на 10-значные номера ($sArea, $sNumber1, $sNumber2, $sNumber3)..